# How do I combine GeoTIFF files covering the same area but storing different data into a single file?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have shapefile cutouts (same shapefile across all images) of different GeoTIFF rasters (with different metadata and sometimes resolutions). How do I merge them into a single GeoTIFF file?

I'm well versed in Python but completely new to GIS, GDAL, and QGIS. Command line, code, and GUI based solutions are all fine.

Comment: close to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763013/r-write-rasterstack-and-preserve-layer-names

Comment: Do you want your images depth-stacked together (like a sandwich?) or are the cutouts of different geographic areas that need to be mosaiced together?

Comment: I find GDALBuildVRT https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_miscellaneous/buildvirtualraster.html very handy, it creates an XML referencing the existing images into a single (small) file which can be used like a single image, from here you can use gdal_translate (QGIS translate raster https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/translate.html) to convert the VRT into a single raster. Both are command line tools if you're not afraid of command line/batch or interested in learning.

Comment: @Charlie Part, like a sandwich. The only adjustment I'd be making is matching resolutions, but all the TIFFs cover the same area

Comment: @ Michael Stimson, that's really cool actually. Could really use it given that only one cities I'm working on already took up 20 GiB of space

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, execute this command inside the directory of GeoTIFF rasters you wish to stack (like a sandwich) together:

```
gdal_merge.py -o your_depth_stack.tif -ps x y -separate *.tif
```

This will stack all images inside the directory. If you only wish to stack a certain subset replace `*.tif` with the desired images: `image1.tif image2.tif image3.tif` etc.

`x` and `y` will control the spatial resolution of your output i.e. `-ps 2 2` will generate 2x2 meter pixels if your data is in UTM, for example.

Other parameters (data type, output extent, etc.) can also be controlled. See the documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html for more direction.